# Binding DropDown to Dictionary with default SelectedIndex

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dropdownbox

I bind a DropDown to a static Dictionary that's always containing n>0 entries

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Localities}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Locality, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    SelectedIndex="0" />
```

And it works just fine, the Dropdown is filled and the values are there and if I select one, the Locality property is written.

Problem is, I *do not* want to have "nothing" selected, but the

```
SelectedIndex="0"
```

property doesn't work as I had expected.

I always want the first item already been selected upon showing.

I assume it's some kind of order problem, that the data binding happens after the SelectedIndex was tried to be set?

Comment: Show your definition for Localities and Locality

Comment: Are you setting the Locality property when the Localities collection is loaded? Does the Locality property trigger a PropertyChanged event when it changes?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the first item within the list.
Hence, the first element sits at index 0.

As a result this element will serve as the selected item.

Instead, consider changing the selected index from "0" to "-1".

```
SelectedIndex="-1"
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear

I _do not_ want that there is no valid selection in the dropdown (i.e. empty) 

Upon display I want the first item already been selected

Comment: Oh... okay. Did you try using an observable collection? Create an ObservableCollection property and throw your Dictionary.Values within its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did it differently and now it works.

Before, I had

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Locality, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
SelectedIndex="0" />
```

And the property was implented as such:

```
public Object Locality
{
  set
  {
    if(value != null)
    {
      LocalityInternal = (Int32)value;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I've changed it to

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Locality}" />
```

And simply fill in the value if need be:

```
public Object Locality
{
  get
  {
    if (LocalityInternal == -1)
    {
      return (0); //this is not the index in the combo box but a dictionary key!
    }
    else
    {
      return (LocalityInternal);
    }
  }
  set
  {
    LocalityInternal = (Int32)value;
  }
}
```